# Cannot read Property 'email' of undefined in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

It has been quite a few days now and I am still struggling in using the third party plugins in my phonegap project. I installed the plugin using phonegap CLI (version 3.4) by the following command:

```
phonegap local plugin add <git repo path>
```

the plugin is successfully added and I can see the packages inside the src folder. I also buld the project for anddroid by this CLI command

```
phonegap build android
```

This also returns a successful response. I have also entered the `gap:plugin` in the config.xml but nothing works. All I get is this error in LogCat

```
[INFO:CONSOLE(265)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined"
```

FYI: I am trying to use [this](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer.git) plugin.This is how I am trying to use this plugin in my js file

```
window.plugin.email.isServiceAvailable(
            function (isAvailable) {
                alert(isAvailable);
            }
        );
```

and this is the entry in cordova_plugins.xml for the plugin:

```
{
        "file": "plugins/de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer/www/email_composer.js",
        "id": "de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer.EmailComposer",
        "clobbers": [
            "plugin.email"
        ]
    }
```

and this is how the code looks like in email_composer.js:

```
cordova.define("de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer.EmailComposer", function(require, exports, module) { 

var EmailComposer = function () {

};

EmailComposer.prototype = {
/**
 * Displays the email composer pre-filled with data.
 *
 * @param {Object} options
 *      Different properties of the email like the body, subject
 * @param {Function} callback
 *      A callback function to be called with the result
 * @param {Object?} scope
 *      The scope of the callback
 */
open: function (options, callback, scope) {
    var callbackFn = this.createCallbackFn(callback, scope),
        options    = options || {};

    var defaults = {
        subject:     null,
        body:        null,
        to:          null,
        cc:          null,
        bcc:         null,
        attachments: null,
        isHtml:      true
    }

    for (var key in defaults) {
        if (options[key] !== undefined) {
            defaults[key] = options[key];
        } else {
            console.log('EmailComposer plugin: unknown property "' + key + '"');
        }
    }

    cordova.exec(callbackFn, null, 'EmailComposer', 'open', [options]);
},

/**
 * Alias fÃ¼r `open()`.
 */
openDraft: function () {
    this.open.apply(this, arguments);
},

/**
 * Verifies if sending emails is supported on the device.
 *
 * @param {Function} callback
 *      A callback function to be called with the result
 * @param {Object} scope
 *      The scope of the callback
 */
isServiceAvailable: function (callback, scope) {
    var callbackFn = this.createCallbackFn(callback, scope);

    cordova.exec(callbackFn, null, 'EmailComposer', 'isServiceAvailable', []);
},

/**
 * @private
 *
 * Creates a callback, which will be executed within a specific scope.
 *
 * @param {Function} callbackFn
 *      The callback function
 * @param {Object} scope
 *      The scope for the function
 *
 * @return {Function}
 *      The new callback function
 */
createCallbackFn: function (callbackFn, scope) {
    return function () {
        if (typeof callbackFn == 'function') {
            callbackFn.apply(scope || this, arguments);
        }
    }
}
};

var plugin = new EmailComposer();

module.exports = plugin;
});
```

note that this `email_composer.js` file is auto generated when I ran the add plugin command. I have not modified it.

Comment: There's a bug in the JavaScript Code. Can you post the code, where this message is generated? Or maybe you forgot to pass some parameters?

Comment: @maja please look for the edits in the question.

Comment: I guess the problem is here? `"clobbers": [ "plugin.email" ]` I guess the file has no access to the "plugin"-Object (it's undefined), and therefore the error appears

Comment: I understand that friend. but this code is auto generated when I downloaded the plugin and also I read it somewhere That one is not meant to edit the 'cordova_plugin.xml' file. Also , I tried various ways to access the 'isServiceAvailable' like 'window.plugin.email.isServiceAvailable' , 'email.isServiceAvailable', 'plugin.email.isServiceAvailable' etc. but nothing works. was trying the hit and trial way.

Comment: @Puneetr90 did you ever figure out what the issue was? I'm running into a similar problem.